# Anonymous function on Validation rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to pass an anonymous function to the Validator in Laravel 4?

I've tried some variations to the code below - but I keep getting exception errors;

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), function() {
                      $array = array(
                                 'dose' => 'Required|AlphaDash',
                                 'volume' => 'Required|AlphaDash',
                                 'repeat' => 'Required|AlphaDash',
                                 'max' => 'Required|AlphaDash');
                       return $array;
                 });
```

Comment: I have not yet seen the L4 source, but have you had a look at the original validation source file to see if the `make()` function even supports closures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since confirmed it is not possible, unless I use something like:

`call_user_func(function() { return true }); :)`